# escape curly braces in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, character, ksh, reserved

I have a string:

`{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}`

I want to append a { at the beginning and a } at the end. The output should be:

`{{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}}`

However, in my shell script when I concatenate the curly braces to the beginning and end of the string, the output is as follows:

`{2013/05/01} {2013/05/02} {2013/05/03}`

Why does this happen? How can I achieve my result? Am sure there is a simple solution to this but I am a unix newbie, thus would appreciate some help.

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
valid_data_range="{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}"
finalDates="{"$valid_data_range"}"
print $finalDates
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you have a list in braces outside quotes, the shell performs [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) (`bash` manual, but [`ksh`](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html) will be similar).  Since the 'outside quotes' bit is important, it also tells you how to avoid the problem — enclose the string in quotes when printing:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh 
valid_data_range="{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}"
finalDates="{$valid_data_range}"
print "$finalDates"
```

(The `print` command is specific to `ksh` and is not present in `bash`.  The change in the assignment line is more cosmetic than functional.)

Also, the brace expansion would not occur in `bash`; it only occurs when the braces are written directly.  This bilingual script (`ksh` and `bash`):

```
valid_data_range="{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}"
finalDates="{$valid_data_range}"
printf "%s\n" "$finalDates"
printf "%s\n" $finalDates
```

produces:

1. `ksh`

   ```
   {{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}}
   {2013/05/01}
   {2013/05/02}
   {2013/05/03}
   ```
2. `bash` (also `zsh`)

   ```
   {{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}}
   {{2013/05/01},{2013/05/02},{2013/05/03}}
   ```

Thus, when you need to use the variable `$finalDates`, ensure it is inside double quotes:

```
other_command "$finalDates"
if [ "$finalDates" = "$otherString" ]
then : whatever
else : something
fi
```

Etc — using your preferred layout for whatever you don't like about mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can say:

```
finalDates=$'{'"$valid_data_range"$'}'
```

Comment: This on its own does not work; you have to prevent the expansion when the variable is used.  The problem is not the assignment, in other words; it is the `print` command.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. So if I want to use the assigned variable, for example, if I want to pass the final string to a function or to another script (maybe python, or perl script) that will use this variable, how can I do that?

Comment: Use `"$finalDates"` or a variation on that (such as `"${finalDates}"`) anywhere you reference the variable and don't want the brace expansion to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the shell is performing brace expansion. This allows you to generate a series of similar strings:

```
$ echo {a,b,c}
a b c
```

That's not very impressive, but consider

```
$ echo a{b,c,d}e
abc ace ade
```

In order to suppress brace expansion, you can use the `set` command to turn it off temporarily

```
$ set +B
$ echo a{b,c,d}e
a{b,c,d}e
$ set -B
$ echo a{b,c,d}e
abe ace ade
```